# Datetime.now not appearing in the file name in carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to upload files. The issue I am facing here that in file name if I just use the model.name then the file uploads perfectly fine and I am able to download the uploaded file. But the issue comes when I add DateTime.now in the file name the the URL appears as below and I not able to download the file. Please help me resolve this issue as I need the DateTime.now in the filename.

```
  def filename
     "#{model.name}-#{DateTime.now)}"
  end

http://localhost:3000/uploads/document/file/91/Time%20Sheet-2020-03-10T16%3A40%3A12-04%3A00
```

Update

```
def filename
    "#{model.name}-#{timestamp}"
  end



  private

  def timestamp
    @timestamp ||= DateTime.now
  end
```

Comment: try to remove `#puts`

Comment: I just had for testing. I have removed it.

Comment: I think https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names should help

Comment: @AlexGolubenko please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
def filename
  "#{model.name}-#{Time.now.strftime("%d:%m:%Y-%H:%M")}"
end
```

This is how it worked for me.